# Intermittent "An EdmType cannot be mapped to CLR classes multiple times" exception

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have an IIS-hosted WCF service that connects to a SQL database backend using Entity Framework 4.1.  Occasionally, I will receive the following exception:

> An EdmType cannot be mapped to CLR classes multiple times.  The
>   EdmType 'Model.EmailTemplate' is mapped more than once. (An item with
>   the same key has already been added.)

This happens rarely enough that I'm not sure it's even always the same class, but there's definitely nothing special about the class mentioned above, and it definitely does not appear in the edmx more than once!  (I believe it simply blames the first class it tries to access after whatever happens that sends Entity Framework off the rails.)

The model is generated from the database tables using the designer and doesn't have any complicated mappings or anything.

When this happens, it will continue to throw that exception until I do an iisreset, and then when it comes back up it's perfectly happy.

This does not appear to be happening in production as far as I'm aware, but it has been happening in both dev and test, two different environments with different SQL server instances.  In both cases, doing an iisreset makes it go away until the next time it becomes offended.

I can't reproduce this consistently enough to be sure when it happens and what is causing it.  However, there are two possible things I can think of:

- The WCF service and a win32 service share the same assemblies and configuration files to connect to the same database.  I guess it's possible some sort of occasional combination of timing between the two of them is annoying one of them, but they're different processes and using different credentials so I'm not sure how they could be affecting each other...
- There is a point where it talks to a second separate database, on which it calls some stored procedures using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`.  It instantiates an EF context just to call `ObjectContext.Translate<ResultSetType>(reader)`.  The result set types that call takes as generic parameters aren't types that are mapped in the context (and notably nothing to do with the type mentioned in the exception above), they're just POCO. Nor are they even connecting to the same database as the object context is on, as the appropriate SqlDataReader is already ready to roll.  The object context is just used as a convenient way of automatically translating entities from the other database.  (This call would be static if a static `Translate<T>(DbDataReader)` existed.)  This is probably what's tripping it up, as it's a bit of a hack and probably doesn't appreciate being used that way... but the block is wrapped in a using (with a TransactionScopeOption.Suppress using directly inside it), so I still feel like it shouldn't have this effect on subsequent calls made with other contexts instantiated later...

Anyone ever run into anything like this?

**Edited to add:**  It is a MappingException, and the stacktrace is below.

```
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TryGetValueLayerType(Type linqType, TypeUsage&amp; type)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetCastTargetType(TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType, Boolean preserveCastForDateTime)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.CreateCastExpression(DbExpression source, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConvertTranslator.TranslateUnary(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression unary, DbExpression operand)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)  
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding&amp; binding)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression&amp; source, DbExpressionBinding&amp; sourceBinding, DbExpression&amp; lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.CopyFrom(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
```

Comment: Do you know the type of the exception? (`MappingException` or `InvalidOperationException`)?

Comment: MappingException; I've edited the question to add that information and a representative stacktrace

Comment: @Grank I know its way back before but have you manage to get rid of that problem? I just ran over this too and... I can't figure out what hapenning here.

Comment: @simon-dugré I don't know if I ever solved this problem, not even sure what project/application this was on... but these days for EF I use a tweaked version of the reverse code-first POCO generator TT you can find on the googles. EDMX is somewhat deprecatedish

Comment: Well, to be honest, that's what I thought... It's an old app that has been started for now 3 or 4 years until it starts to crash a month ago.. It all appears to be a Windows Update during that week. Thanks